# p4 tag lots of files from command line

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to tag with perforce a sizable number of files?

Our depot (more precisely, the part of my company's shared depot where our code resides) has over 20k files, and our build process needs to tag a subset, say in the 3k to 7k files range.

There is no changelist with the files to tag, just a plain text list.  We cannot feed the whole list to the CLI p4, as the command line would be too long. We currently tag directory by directory, but this involves a lot of p4 invocations and is a bit slow.

Is there a way to tell p4 to tag all files listed "in this file"?  Note that to create a changelist I would be faced with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-x` flag.  It'll read from the file and batch up the command automatically.

```
p4 -x FILELIST.txt tag -l LABEL
```

FWIW, in my experience creating giant static labels as part of a build process is usually a clue that something is being made more complicated than it needs to be -- either the build process or the branching structure is poorly designed if you need to label everything you build rather than being able to just do `p4 changes -m1 PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, keep forgetting to do "p4 help usage", where the -x flag is conveniently hidden ;-)  We have no branches, just mainline (LabVIEW, you can branch but you can never merge!) Not sure what p4 changes will do to help us go back to an old build.

Comment: Run `p4 changes -m1` before you do the build.  That number is your label (but minus having to create the label).

Comment: Running "p4 changes -m1"  gives a changelist affecting elsewhere on the depot.  From our root "p4 change -m1 ..." gives me the last changelist one of us made.  Not sure that is enough. With labels I can quickly see in a file history, which revisions of that file went into which build, and we do that often.  Having to sync to a changelist to check for that seems a little bit cumbersome.

Comment: Do `p4 changes -m1 PATH` on the path you built, and the `CHANGE` you get back will henceforth behave exactly like if you'd done `p4 tag -l LABEL PATH#head` at that same time.  You can do `p4 files PATH@CHANGE` and it will return the same results as `p4 files PATH@LABEL` would have (actually it's more accurate, because it'll include deleted revisions rather than omitting them as labels do by default).  Do `p4 sync PATH@CHANGE` and you can recreate your build.  This indexing happens automatically *and* is orders of magnitude more performant than static labels are.  `@DATE` works too!

Comment: I should note also that even if you omit the `PATH` and use the changelist number from "another part of the depot", it can still be used as a "label" for the files you built (try it)!